# Converting values to a character missing value in SAS

Tags: sas

Hi I am having trouble with this question related to a school project. Converting values to a character missing value.

Run the following program to create the Dataset NOTAPPLY.

```
DATA NOTAPPLY;

LENGTH A B C D E $ 2;

INPUT ID A $ B $ C $ D $ E $ X Y Z;

DATALINES;

001 Y N N Y Y 1 2 3

002 na NA Y Y Y 3 4 5

003 NA NA NA na na 8 9 10

;
```

In the SAS data set NOTAPPLY, a value of either NA or na was used in place of a
missing value for all character variables. Create a new SAS data set NEW where
these values are converted to a character missing value.

Comment: [How to ask homework questions on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/13138364)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the link tdy posted; as it stands, this question doesn't fit our community guidelines.  In particular, you need to either ask a very specific question about a particular language feature, or you need to post the code that you have written that does not accomplish what you are looking to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of converting values in SAS. One of them is using an INFORMAT by importing data. So you code might look like:

```
proc format;
  invalue $MYMISS
    'NA'='  '
    'na'='  '
  ;
run;

DATA NEW;

  LENGTH A B C D E $ 2;

  INPUT ID A:$MYMISS2. B:$MYMISS2. C:$MYMISS2. D:$MYMISS2. E:$MYMISS2. X Y Z;

  DATALINES;
001 Y N N Y Y 1 2 3
002 na NA Y Y Y 3 4 5
003 NA NA NA na na 8 9 10    
;
run;
```